# Open a storyboard view with a stackview button in Swift 3 and Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have three views in my storyboard: MainViewController, EditViewController and PatchViewController.

In my Main view I've added a Horizontal Stack View-object which has its own class (*class FieldController: UIStackView*) where I add three buttons programatically. 
Depending on some dynamic values, clicking on one of these buttons should open either the Edit or Patch-view which also should have access to an id that corresponds to what button clicked.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hint: Use named segues combined with an IBAction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create segues in your storyboard from main controller to your additional controllers and set different identifier for each segue. In my example I'm using EditSegueIdentifier and PatchSegueIdentifier

Then in your main controller:

```
//connect IBActions to each button, or your buttons may have one action to connect to, but have also different tags, like below:
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //You can send an ID as Int for example, to catch them in prepareForSegue method. 
    //You can send any values or objects as sender, 
    //also it can be a tag of clicked button, whatever you want.
    switch sender.tag{
        case 1:
          performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditSegueIdentifier", sender: YourIDForEDIT)
        case 2:
          performSegue(withIdentifier: "PatchSegueIdentifier", sender: YourIDForPATCH)
        default: break
    }

}
```

If you are using programatically created buttons, you can make same thing inside their selector method:

```
func setTargets(){
    let selector = #selector(buttonAction(_:))
    yourFirstButton.tag = 1
    yourFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)

   yourSecondButton.tag = 2
   yourSecondButton.addTarget(self, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
}

func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton){
     switch sender.tag{
            case 1:
              performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditSegueIdentifier", sender: YourIDForEDIT)
            case 2:
              performSegue(withIdentifier: "PatchSegueIdentifier", sender: YourIDForPATCH)
            default: break
        }
}
```

Then we need to prepare values to send to additional controllers

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        //check segue identifier for sending values to destination controller
        if segue.identifier == "EditSegueIdentifier", let editID = sender as? Int {

            let destination = segue.destination as? EditViewController
            destination?.id = editID        
        }

        if segue.identifier == "PatchSegueIdentifier", let patchID = sender as? Int {

            let destination = segue.destination as? PatchViewController
            destination?.id = patchID        
        }
}
```

==============EDIT==================

The protocol

```
protocol YourStackViewDelegate {
    func performButtonAction(with index: Int) //or you can send anything else (e.g. ID, objects)
}
```

Then in your StackViewClass

```
class YourStackViewClass {
   //make optional var for delegate instance
    var delegate: YourStackViewDelegate?

   func setTargets(){
        let selector = #selector(buttonAction(_:))
        yourFirstButton.tag = 1
        yourFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)

       yourSecondButton.tag = 2
       yourSecondButton.addTarget(self, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton){
         //call the method from the protocol
         delegate?.performButtonAction(with: sender.tag)
    }
}
```

In your view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   yourStackView.delegate = self
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            //check segue identifier for sending values to destination controller
         if segue.identifier == "EditSegueIdentifier", let editID = sender as? Int {

             let destination = segue.destination as? EditViewController
             destination?.id = editID        
         }

         if segue.identifier == "PatchSegueIdentifier", let patchID = sender as? Int {

             let destination = segue.destination as? PatchViewController
             destination?.id = patchID        
         }
  }
```

Then add an extension of you view controller with the delegate

```
extension YourViewController: YourStackViewDelegate {
    func performButtonAction(with index: Int) {
         switch index{
                case 1:
                  performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditSegueIdentifier", sender: YourIDForEDIT)
                case 2:
                  performSegue(withIdentifier: "PatchSegueIdentifier", sender: YourIDForPATCH)
                default: break
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm getting an error though: "Use of unresolved identifier 'performSegue'". This function doesnt seem to exist in a UIStackView(where my buttons are created)? I can call it if I run MainViewController().performSegue(), but then my created segue seems to be lost: "has no segue with identifier "PatchSegueIdentifier".

Comment: The performSegue method should be called in the view controller. You can use protocol to send any data or actions from your custom stack class to the view controller. Let me know if you need a code for it, I will edit my answer

Comment: If you could provide code for it it would be great. I've tried a few times my self now without success.

Comment: I've edited my answer, check it. Let me know if you need something

Comment: Edit: As soon as I wrote a question, I figured that "yourStackView" is a IBOutlet, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. You need to connect it with your view controller

Comment: Thanks a lot Woof for tremendous help!