# Ios - change image of UIImageView when pressing a UIButton

Tags: ios

So I am developing my first app in iOS and I don't know how to fix this. In the same view I have:
 - two `buttons` inside a `stackView` (that I modified)
 - an `UIImageView`
[Storyboard View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrlOb.png)

Depending on which button I press, I want the image to change in `UIImageView`. However, bc the buttons are in the `stackView`, I can't push an `IBAction` from them to the controller.

I changed the image based on the button inside the function **didViewLoad()**, but as I learned, that function is only called once, so when when I press the `buttons` in the app it has no more effect in the `UIImageView`.

This is my controller for this view
[Controller Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccFJA.png)

And this is the beginning of the code for the subclass of the UIStackView
[UIStackView subclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/minZ4.png)

Comment: It should not be a problem to create `IBAction`s for the buttons even when they are embedded in a `UIStackView`.

Comment: I embedded it when I was writing my own subclass of UIStackView, so when I go to storyboard, it displays the buttons inside the StackView, but I doesn't let me select or drag them to my controller. The only thing I can drag is the stackView, and that doesn't have the option for IBAction, just IBOutlet

Comment: Please show some code of your custom `UIStackView` class. Do you create the buttons programmatically in that class?

Comment: ***Why*** are you subclassing `UIStackView`?

Comment: This is from how I learned in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1.   I wanted to have the buttons connected, so when I press one button, the other automatically is unselected. I could probably just have created two buttons, but I will likely need more of these stack view with more than just 2 buttons, and would be good to know how to fix it now rather than later

Comment: You could also think about using a `UISegmentedControl` for your use case of only one button being selected at a time.

Comment: @DanielLima - OK... following that tutorial, it shows how to connect the buttons to actions *inside* the custom control (the subclassed `UIStackView`). After that, you'll want to implement a delegate / protocol pattern to allow the custom control - ***not the buttons themselves*** - to communicate back to the view controller when the "rating" has changed.

Comment: @AndréSlotta I'm also surprised no one noticed that either

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Segmented Controller would be a good idea for this case. Thank you for that.

For the more general approach of how to make things happen with what I had already written, this post ([Open a storyboard view with a stackview button in Swift 3 and Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659269/open-a-storyboard-view-with-a-stackview-button-in-swift-3-and-xcode)) was very useful and also taught me how to properly use protocols and delegates.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, you also have the option of using Segmented Controller.

Place the segmented controller in your View Controller in the StoryBoard.

Make an outlet of the Segment Controller

```
@IBOutlet var segmentedController: UISegmentedControl!
```

Make an `IBAction` Function for `Value Changed` event in the Segmented Control. Now whenever the selected tabs are changed you will be notified.

```
@IBAction func SegmentTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    switch segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        // Change Image Here
    case 1:
        // Change other image here
    default:
        // Statement to execute if no other case is present
    }
}
```